# Setting up bcrypt to work with Passport and async-await Node.js library

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, passport.js, bcrypt

I’m using yortus’ [async/await](https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait) node.js library to setup a Passport based login/signup system with passwords hashed using [bcrypt-nodejs](https://github.com/shaneGirish/bcryptJS).

While the rest of the system is setup and functioning properly, I’m having trouble getting `bcrypt-nodejs` to work nicely with yortus' `async/await` because the bcrypt hashing function signature requires two callbacks and it’s not clear how to use it with `async/await`...

```
hash(data, salt, progress, cb)
    data - [REQUIRED] - the data to be encrypted.
    salt - [REQUIRED] - the salt to be used to hash the password.
    progress - a callback to be called during the hash calculation to signify progress
    callback - [REQUIRED] - a callback to be fired once the data has been encrypted.
        error - First parameter to the callback detailing any errors.
        result - Second parameter to the callback providing the encrypted form.
```

The `async/await` call...

```
let generateHash = async((password) => {
    let salt = await(bcrypt.genSaltAsync(10)) // this works
    let result = await(bcrypt.hash(password, salt, null)
    return result // returns NULL
})
```

Output:

```
Unhandled rejection No callback function was given.
```

Database entry (MongoDB) when I try to signup using the system:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581bf7031386f167a09851b9"),
    "username" : "vjk2005",
    "password" : ""
}
```

Username goes through but the password is `NULL`. I have tried a number of permutations and combinations without success, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest just using `babel` with regular `async/await` keyword or the `--harmony-async-await` flag on Node 7.  Will make the code cleaner, and I think very few people use that library.  They took the idea and made it into part of the language.

Even if you use that library, it needs promisified functions rather than ones using callbacks.  You can use the `pify` module or find a promisified bcrypt.  Always search on npmjs.com or npms.io.  Search for like 'bcrypt promise'.

```
import {hash} from 'bcrypt-as-promised';

const generateHash = async password => await hash(password, 10);

generateHash('abc1234').then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Or since you can autogenerate the salt like that you could simplify it to:

```
import {hash} from 'bcrypt-as-promised';

hash('abc123',10).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: I’m actually using Bluebird to promisify the bcrypt lib. I’ll reserve harmony and babel as my last resort.